# Remove z-index property in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

I want to remove the z-index property in internet explorer only as because it does not work properly in internet explorer.
I designed a site with eBook flip functionality. It works well in all browsers except Internet explorer

so I want to use z-index for all other browsers except IE
like: use of -webkit-, -moz- ,
but it doesn't work with z-index

Comment: I believe this post answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135803/compiling-and-maintaining-ie-specific-stylesheets

Comment: It also good idea, but right now I can't use sass.
I have to solve this by normal CSS or JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var ie_check = msieversion();  
 if (ie_check != true )
  {
      $(selector).css('z-index',11)
  }   
}

function msieversion()
{
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
   if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))     
        return true;
    else                 
        return false;
   return false;
}
```

Try This It's May help you

Answer (score 0):

The z-index bug in old Internet Explorer editions are well documented.

Try giving the **parent** a higher z-index.
This is a work around that works most of the times.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    div {
        zoom: 2; /* for all browsers */
        zoom: normal\9; /* for IE, set zoom to default value "normal" */
    }
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer to make it more useful to other readers.

Comment: http://showcase.tulipinfotek.com/ebook/
here I have design a ebook opening effect
but you will see it looks defferent in IE and Crome

If I will remove z-index in IE from .bk-book selector it will fix